# Unable to find the requested Boost libraries Windows Cmake

Tags: c++, c, windows, boost, cmake

I'm trying to build [Bytecoin](https://github.com/amjuarez/bytecoin) source on Windows and I'm running into issues with CMake and Boost libraries. First I tried grabbing the Boost 1.55 and compiling it myself. One or two of the libs near the end did not compile for some reason but I thought that CMake would at least identify the compiled libraries. Instead, I get this error when trying to load the CMake project:

> Error:Unable to find the requested Boost libraries. Boost version:
>   1.55.0 Boost include path: C:/Program Files/boost/boost_1_55_0 Could not find the following Boost libraries:
>           boost_system         boost_filesystem         boost_thread         boost_date_time         boost_chrono         boost_regex
>   boost_serialization         boost_program_options No Boost libraries
>   were found.  You may need to set BOOST_LIBRARYDIR to the directory
>   containing Boost libraries or BOOST_ROOT to the location of Boost.

Then I tried adding a HINT to the find_package(). It tried to parse a weird path, not sure where it's doing this:

> CMake Error at C:/Program Files
>   (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.4/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:273 (if):   Syntax
>   error in cmake code at
>
> ```
> C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.4/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:273
> ```
>
> when parsing string
>
> ```
> ${Boost_C:/PROGRAM FILES/BOOST/BOOST_1_55_0_LIBRARY_RELEASE}
> ```

Reading some of the SO answers on the matter I added environment variables:

> C:\Users\Misha>set
>
> BOOST_INCLUDEDIR=C:\local\boost_1_55_0
>   BOOST_LIBRARYDIR=C:\local\boost_1_55_0\lib32-msvc-12.0
>   BOOST_ROOT=C:\local\boost_1_55_0\boost

At this point I tried using the [precompiled libs](http://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost-binaries/1.55.0-build2/), nothing.

**CMkeLists.txt**

```
find_package(Boost 1.55 REQUIRED COMPONENTS system filesystem thread date_time chrono regex serialization program_options)
#find_package(Boost 1.55 REQUIRED COMPONENTS system filesystem thread date_time chrono regex serialization program_options HINT "C:/Program Files/boost/boost_1_55_0")
include_directories(SYSTEM ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
if (MINGW)
    set(Boost_LIBRARIES "${Boost_LIBRARIES};ws2_32;mswsock")
elseif (APPLE)
    set(Boost_LIBRARIES "${Boost_LIBRARIES}")
elseif (NOT MSVC)
    set(Boost_LIBRARIES "${Boost_LIBRARIES};rt")
endif ()
```

I'm not familiar with CMake, so it is likely a simple fix. I just can't see it.

Comment: Insert `set(Boost_DEBUG on)` before `find_package()` and rerun cmake. In debug mode all searched libraries will be shown. Check that all these libraries exist under the directory you assign to variable `BOOST_LIBRARYDIR`. `HINT` option is unrelated to your problem, as it is used for `Config` mode of [find_package](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/find_package.html), but you use `Module` mode (`FindBoost.cmake`).

Comment: @Tsyvarev It looks like boost_serialization is causing problems at _least_

`Could not find the following static Boost libraries: boost_serialization`

Comment: @Tsyvarev It appears to be in the directory, so I'm not quite sure why it isn't found

Comment: It should be line `Searching for <component>_LIBRARY_RELEASE: `, where precise filenames are given (component is one which you specify in `find_package()`).

Comment: The error that mentions `BOOST_1_55_0_LIBRARY_RELEASE` makes me think that cmake is somehow treating `1.55` as a boost library, as if it were part of the `COMPONENTS` list.  I don't think you're doing anything wrong, but maybe try removing the `1.55` argument from `find_package()`

Comment: anyone found any solution for this? Stuck at same problem for 2 days

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same error, but resolved it. My BOOST Library was build using Gcc 6.3 on windows 7 (64 Bit).

I set `Boost_DEBUG on` in `CMakeLists.txt` and found

> -- [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.9/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1620 ] Searching
>   for SYSTEM_LIBRARY_RELEASE:
>   libboost_system-mgw63-mt-1_67;libboost_system-mgw63-mt;libboost_system-mt-1_67;libboost_system-mt;libboost_system

That means `FindPackage(Boost)` is searching for `libboost_system-mgw63-mt-1_67` but my library name was `libboost_system-mgw63-mt-x64-1_67`.

So I removed `X64` from all libray names and now it is working properly.

Comment: I feel like renaming all the libraries isn't the proper way to resolve this. Does anyone know if there's a more formal solution?